# How do You change a variable to a string in python?

Tags: python

So I am trying to change a randomized variable to a string with a function, any ideas why this isn't working?

```
def letter(x):
    if x == 1:
            x = "A"
    elif x == 2:
            x = "C"
    elif x == 3:
            x = "G"
    elif x == 4:
            x = "T"
    else:
            print "Error" 
randint18= random.randrange(1,5)
letter(randint18)
print randint18 `
```

Comment: Back away your python console slowly, take a breath, and go read [this article](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mine isn't a proper answer, which have been provided already, but a suggestion for improving your code. I'd do it in a comment, but the code formatting ain't good enough.

Why not use a dictionary for the mapping, instead of a sequence of if's? You could still place it in a function if you like:

```
letter = {1:'A', 2:'C', 3:'G', 4:'T'}
randint18 = random.randrange(1,5)
mapping = letter.get(randint18, 'Error')
print mapping
```

mind you, a list would be even more efficient, if the mapping started form zero:

```
letter = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']
randint18 = random.randrange(0,4)
try: # in case your random index were allowed to go past 3
 mapping = letter[randint18]
except IndexError:
 mapping = 'Error'
print mapping
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to return the value from the function, and assign it to a variable.

```
def letter(x):
    ...
    return x


randint18 = random.randrange(1, 5)
result = letter(randint18)
print result
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if this was a dumb question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot alter the variable in place you must return it and capture the returned value.

```
import random

def letter(x):
    if x == 1:
            x = "A"
    elif x == 2:
            x = "C"
    elif x == 3:
            x = "G"
    elif x == 4:
            x = "T"
    else:
        print "Error" 
    return x  # return it here

randint18= random.randrange(1,5)
randint18 = letter(randint18)  # capture the returned value here 
print randint18
```

There is a simpler way to achieve what you want, using a dictionary to map the values.

```
import random

def letter(x):
    mapd = {1:'A', 2:'C', 3:'G', 4:'T'}
    return mapd.get(x, None)

randint18= random.randrange(1,5)
randint18 = letter(randint18)
print randint18
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include a return in your function

```
def letter(x):
    if x == 1:
            x = "A"
    elif x == 2:
            x = "C"
    elif x == 3:
            x = "G"
    elif x == 4:
            x = "T"
    else:
            print "Error" 
    return x
randint18 = random.randrange(1,5)
returned_result = letter(randint18)
print returned_result
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a return value of the function

```
return x
```

value_you_want = letter(randint18) ##add the return statement. Output will be saved to value_you_want

Please note that the variables defined inside a function are local to the function and cannot be accessed outside the scope of the function. You were expecting the value of x outside the function which is not possible. Just to check run your function and try to access the value in variable x. It will give error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    print x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```